# Svelte: pre-selecting a select input option when using objects as values

Tags: svelte

I have a couple of components built around vanilla select fields which have been working fine until I recently updated Svelte.

I'm using objects as values, which seems to be supported just fine by Svelte. Previously, this would also pre-select the matching option in the select field. However, now it just shows the select as empty.

In this example, how can I have the select field show the option already stored in `chosen`?

```
<script>
    let opts = [
        {pk:1, name:"first"},
        {pk:2, name:"second"},
        {pk:3, name:"third"},
    ]
    let chosen = {pk:2, name:"second"}
</script>

<select bind:value={chosen}>
    {#each opts as opt}<option value={opt}>{opt.name}</option>{/each}
</select>
<hr>
chosen: &lbrace;pk: {chosen.pk}, name:"{chosen.name}"&rbrace;
```

**Update** it looks like I'm possibly hitting a known issue:

[select option with default selection.... broken in 3.42?](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6954)

More importantly, I think it has highlighted a gap in my understanding of Svelte...selection here is determined by identity and not equality (taken from the comments on the issue):

> It works fine to bind to an object, but the selected variable needs to be a reference to the desired value (rather than a different object copy) so that strict equality comparison will work.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set the chosen like this `let chosen = opts[1]`?

Comment: This `$: chosen = opts.filter(opt => opt.name === 'second')[0]` would be an alternative if only the props of the element are known but not the index

Comment: See the updated answer, i added an explanation of what changed

Comment: This is not specific to Svelte. Object equality in javascript is based on reference and not value (try evaluating `{a: 0, b: "foo"} === {a: 0, b: "foo"}` in your browser console). This is why using scalars (where equality is strictly based on value) is a better option.

Answer (score 4):

You should use scalars for the `option` values as well as for the `select` bound variable:

```js
<script>
    let opts = [
        {pk:1, name:"first"},
        {pk:2, name:"second"},
        {pk:3, name:"third"},
    ]
    let chosen = 2
    $: current = opts.find(opt => opt.pk === chosen)
</script>

<select bind:value={chosen}>
    {#each opts as opt}<option value={opt.pk}>{opt.name}</option>{/each}
</select>
<hr>
chosen: &lbrace;pk: {current.pk}, name:"{current.name}"&rbrace;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use `chosen = opts[number]` for some reason, you can work around that by converting the selected value to a string

```
<script>
    let opts = [
        {pk:1, name:"first"},
        {pk:2, name:"second"},
        {pk:3, name:"third"},
    ]
        let selected = JSON.stringify({pk:2, name:"second"})
    $: chosen = JSON.parse(selected);
</script>

<select bind:value={selected}>
    {#each opts as opt,index}
        <option value={JSON.stringify(opt)}>{opt.name}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
<hr>
chosen: &lbrace;pk: {chosen?.pk}, name:"{chosen?.name}"&rbrace;
```

your method was working until version `3.42.2` and what changed then

> Deselect all `<option>`s in a  where the bound value doesn't match any of them

so now you are comparing two diffrent objects, that's why it doesn't work anymore.